# Sound programing in php

Tags: php

I want to make program for pronounce of alphabets characters like as in recaptcha.For some alphabets this should pronounce with related characters individual.

Is it possible also in javascipt otherwise php is ok?

I need what should be concept or programming tips will appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: Your PHP is running on the server.  Don't think you want to hear the characters pronounced there, do you?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do - have a webpage pronounce some text? PHP won't help you there, you'd have to use JS (and/or Flash)

Comment: I am making code like captcha i have done all module but now how will i make code for sound ?If somebody will click on sound icon than each text character should pronounce so user can hear the exact word.

Answer (score 2):

Create an index of sound files that contain each individual letter pronounced.

To pronounce a word (letter by letter) stitch the corresponding sound files together on the server side using an appropriate sound editing program. I would recommend [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) for that. It's a command line tool that does that and many more.

Generate the "stitched" file in a temporary location and serve it to the browser. You can use a flash mp3 player to play it.

Answer (score 0):

In case it is a Linux/Unix server and you are able to install additional extension in PHP (p.e. have root rights) you could try this Extension: http://pecl.php.net/package/FliteTTS source via http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/flitetts/trunk/